# 3D Rotation of a pose around origin

Tags: python, transformation, ros, euler-angles

I want to transform a pose around origin. The pose I have contains a position [x,y,z] and an orientation [x,y,z,w] represented as a quaternion. I have a 4x4 transformation matrix which I use to translate and rotate the position of the pose around origin.

```
np.dot(transforma_mat, np.transpose(np.append(pose.position, 1)))
```

So, as the origin moves and rotates, the starting point of the pose also moves and rotates. However, I am not sure how I can rotate the orientation of the pose.

I can convert the quaternion to Euler angles and rotation matrix (and vice versa) using [this library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html).

The story:
There is an object which moves and rotates. The robot end-effector has a pose before the object moves and rotates. I want to update the pose of the end-effector such that it moves and rotates with the object.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?  I take it there is an "external" coordinate system and a "robot" coordinate system.  You have the vector that separates the origins from these two coordinate systems, and a rotation matrix which aligns the two coordinate systems once their origins match.  What exactly do you need help with from there?

Comment: I wrote the story. You can assume that there is only one coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to translate an object with respect to another object's movement can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282026/3d-rotation-of-an-object-with-respect-to-another-objects-rotation).

Try to convert the rotations to matrices. Euler angles didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it with quaternions, however, you could define your orientation as two orthogonal vectors (abiding by the right or left handed rule).

You could then simply multiply these vectors in your coordinate system by your transformation matrices to get the transformed orientation.

Comment: Thank you. How can I define the orientation as 2 orthogonal vectors?

Comment: Your orientation could be defined any way you'd like. You could define Z vector as a "look" direction, and Y as an "up" direction. You would define these vectors in reference to the initial coordinate system. Then you can transform both of them with your rotation matrices.

Comment: This is often done in 3d graphics. Maybe this will help: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial13/tutorial13.html

Answer (score 0):

As I know you from rotation matrices you can get the Euler angles and quaternion. So do your move for the Rotation matrix and then Get the orientation (GEnerally, Transformation matrix fives you all the information about the orientation)

Answer (score 0):

With quaternion is it quite easy. First, convert your rotation matrix to quaternion q and the translation vector t.

Translation and rotation of points is simple. First add the translation to the point. Then, simply apply the quaternion q to the translated point x. Here, the point x is extended to that it becomes a quaternion with weight w=0. The multiplication is Hamilton product (quaternion multiplication).

```
x' = q * x * q'
```

In order to rotate the quaternion q2 associated with each pose, multiply your quaternion q from left by q2:

```
q2' = q2 * q
```